# Creates folder/file with second user permission on linux Centos

Tags: linux, permissions, centos6

Linux permission question:
I have one folder "test" with a permission group "test", the primary group for "test" user is "users" and the second group is "test"
How to make the second group "test" to receive permission when a user "test" is create a folder or file in the /test directory?

The group "users" don't need to have access to the "test" user folder.

After the user "test" creates a new folder/file inside the "test" directory it need to be will show as following:

$ll /test
drwxr-xr-x   2 test test qa/

not:
$ll /test
drwxr-xr-x   2 test users  qa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <del>sticky bit</del> `setguid` (an `s` attribute) attribute on folder. It ensures all new files or folders created in it will inherit it's <del>rights</del> group id. For exmaple:

```
 mkdir test
 sudo chown jask:root test
 sudo chmod g+s test
 touch test/test_file
 ll test/

 -rw-rw-r-- 1 jask root 0 15. pro 11.46 test_file
```

Similarly you can use setuid `chmod u+s` for inheriting owner (uid).

When used not on folders but executables it has different meaning. For more reference use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: That's not how sticky bit works and the bit you set in in the example is setgid. Also there is already a directory with sticky bit -- /tmp. If it worked the way you describe, it would be unusable.

Comment: You are right, I got it mixed. I'll corect my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, with "chmod g+s test" and add the user to test group.
So anyone who is in the test group inheriting the GID from  the top folder.